# Gitlab webhook can't be triggered on Azure DevOps Server Version 2020.1.RC2

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2020

Incoming webhook can be triggered on Azure DevOps Server Version **Dev18.M170.6**, but it can't be triggered on Azure DevOps Server **2020.1.RC2**.

I'm getting an error message from the **2020.1.RC2**:

`Cannot find webhook for the given webHookId CodeSyncTrigger. Try enabling CD trigger for this artifact.`

Below are snapshots of testing related APIs using postman.

Invoke Azure DevOps Server **2020.1.RC2** 6.0-preview incoming webhook API:
[image: Invoke Azure DevOps Server 2020.1.RC2 6.0-preview incoming webhook API]

Invoke Azure DevOps Server **Dev18.M170.6** 6.0-preview incoming webhook API with HTTP status 200 OK:
[image: Invoke Azure DevOps Server Dev18.M170.6 6.0-preview incoming webhook API with HTTP status 200 OK]

Is there a way to make it work on the Azure DevOps Server 2020.1.RC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause!!!

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-use-generic-webhook-based-triggers-for-yaml/1135943#T-N1203277

> 1. The service connection name does not need to be the same as the
>    webhook name. The webhook name is what needs to be used in the API
>    url. The service connection name is what needs to be referenced in the
>    "connection:" line of the yml.
> 2. The webhook name cannot be the naming convention/schema of an Azure
>    DevOps Project ID (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
> 3. After creating/modifying the webhook service connection, you must
>    make a change(and commit) to each azure-pipeline.yml that references
>    that webhook service connection for it to take effect for that
>    repo/pipeline. A simple #comment will do.
> 4. The "webhook:" (alias) line in the azure-pipelines.yml cannot have
>    a hyphen, or your yaml will be invalid and the webhook won't work (see
>    #5).
> 5. The azure-pipelines.yml must not have any errors. To verify, try
>    running the pipeline manually. If the pipeline initiates, then you
>    should be good.
> 6. It will only trigger the master branch. If you add the webhooks
>    resource config to a non-master branch, it will not get triggered
>    (this is a huge letdown for us*).
> 7. You cannot use wildcards in the filters (this is also a huge
>    letdown for us*).

Answer (score 0):

In my case solution was to change default branch because of I host yaml not in master branch

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-default-branch?view=azure-devops#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20a%20pipeline's%20default,...%20and%20select%20Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-default-branch?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20a%20pipeline%27s%20default,...%20and%20select%20Triggers).